# Confusing results when trying to align viewport to camera with Python

Tags: python, 3d-view, camera

I have a scene with a 40mm camera, for a reference I put some boxes that visually touch camera region borders. Viewport is close to 16:9 — just like the scene format.

[image]

Then I disable the camera view and go my viewport (also set to 40mm) with `Numpad-0` and run an operator with this code, that should put my viewport to the same position as camera.

```py
cam_mw = context.scene.camera.matrix_world
context.area.spaces.active.region_3d.view_matrix = cam_mw.inverted()
```

However my viewport seems to be *much* further away than needed, and the issue seems to be not the viewport location, but focal length.

[image]

If I eyeball viewport focal length parameter to sometime around 87mm it seems to fit the camera view:

[image]

My question is, what comes into work here, why viewport and camera with the same FL and coordinates/rotation don't look the same? What should I change so that viewport would look the same as the camera view? I have a feeling that Camera Sensor Size (35mm by default) has something to do with that but not sure what are the calculations to be made.

Scene: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/m45ptdeaqo4ydmxlvswbs/cam_test.blend?rlkey=u8g0h1qzkqavlkio90tpn27ry&dl=1